# How to pass list of strings to view with action result method in ASP dotNet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ActionResult Method which i wanted to return some values to the view for using in a form to submit afterwards.
How can I access these data from view for submition in a form?!

Here is my ActionResult method:

```
  

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> ImportPhonenumbersFromExcel(IFormFile importexcelfile, int currentFestivalId)
    {

        if (!await _permissionService.AuthorizeAsync(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageFestivals))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        try
        {
            if (importexcelfile != null && importexcelfile.Length > 0)
            {
                var result = await _importManager.ImportPhonenumbersFromXlsxAsync(importexcelfile.OpenReadStream());

            }
            else
            {
                _notificationService.ErrorNotification(await _localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Admin.Common.UploadFile"));
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = currentFestivalId });
            }
            _notificationService.SuccessNotification(await _localizationService.GetResourceAsync("Admin.Festival.Phonenumbers.Imported"));
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = currentFestivalId });

        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            await _notificationService.ErrorNotificationAsync(em);
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = currentFestivalId });
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your view , do you use ajax?

Comment: You can create a model to contain your values and pass the model from controller to the view.

Comment: No ajax used in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For strongly typed data a **view model** is the best option. It is a class with properties that can be used to store your specific values which you want to pass to the view. To use a *viewmodel*:

- Create the *viewmodel* class and add the properties you need.
- Instantiate a new *viewmodel* object in your controller. The example shown below is from the Microsoft documentation where the *viewmodel* class is named Address.

  ```
   public IActionResult Contact()
   {
       ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

       var viewModel = new Address()
       {
           Name = "Microsoft",
           Street = "One Microsoft Way",
           City = "Redmond",
           State = "WA",
           PostalCode = "98052-6399"
       };

       return View(viewModel);
   }
  ```
- Once you have set the values of the properties of the *viewmodel* object in the controller you can then add the *viewmodel* to the view.
- To send the *viewmodel* to the view, pass it as a parameter:

  `return View(viewModel);`
- Finally, add to the top of your view file:

  `@model yourViewModelsAddress`

To refer to the properties of your *viewmodel* in your view, follow this example:

```
`@Model.Property`
```

Comment: thanks buddy. It may be helpful but I have some **return** statements and they are needed to be redirected to previous page. Any idea about how send these data to view without View() method?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view model that will contain the list and everything else you want to pass to the view.

Then in the view you can access it by using @model.